# When Domain is totally bounded, cauchy continuity implies uniform continuity

Tags: metric-spaces

X and Y are metric spaces.
f is a cauchy continuous function from X to Y. 
If X is totally bounded then f is uniformly continuous.
I am really confused how to use the total boundedness.
Can I have some help with this problem?